# Laravel - How to make a scope with an array of Values?

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

i have an array with Manufacturers and now I want to make a scope to get only a result of products which only have the value of the array as Manufacturer.

This is my actual scope, but it doesnt work.

```
public function scopeManufacturer($query, array $manufacturer)
{
    return $query->where(function($query) use ($manufacturer) {
        $str = '';
        foreach($manufacturer as $man){
            $str .=  "->where('category', " . $man ;
        }

        return $query . $str;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use *whereIn*:

```
public function scopeManufacturer($query, array $manufacturer)
{
    return $query->whereIn('category', $manufacturer);
}
```

First parameter is the name of the column you're searching in; second parameter is the array of values that you're trying to match.